# An aspect about Taylor expansion convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

This is the conceptual question:

Is there any general way to know if a Taylor expansion about a point converges faster than the analogous expansion about another point? 
For example, when approximating the value of $\exp(x)$ about $x=4$ it wouldn't be the same with $f(x + a_{1})$ for $a_{1}=0$ or $a_{1}=1$.
I thought that maybe the derivative of the residue could help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The rate of convergence of a power series is related to its radius of convergence; and for (complex-)analytic functions, the radius of convergence of a power series is the distance from the center point to the nearest singularity of the function.

Comment: Does it means that if i want to approximmate **lnx** in x=1.1, center the expansion in a=1 would be faster than a=2, for example? Because it has a singularity in x=0

Comment: Yes. The former expansion converges roughly like $[(1.1-1)/(1-0)]^n$, the latter expansion like $[(2-1.1)/(2-0)]^n$. (Understanding why these are the correct rates of convergence is an excellent exercise for you!)